# Firebase authentication - prevent access to unknown users

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebase on my angular app.
Right now, what I want to do is pretty simple.

I have data in my app, that I want to be accesible only to certain users, to whom I sent a registration link.

This registration link sends the user to a page where they can fill in their personal information (name, phonenumber, birthdate) and choose a way to authentify themselves: email/password or Google sign-in.

On another page, let's call it 'login page', they sign-in using the same way they used when registering.

If they chose email/password, everything works fine, I can limit access only to users who previously registered and verified their email adress.

But when using google sign-in, anyone with a google account can access all the data on the app, even if they didn't register before.

As far as I know, it's because email/password authentication uses two steps:

```
createUserWithemailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Which creates a new user

```
signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
```

Which authenticates the user, only if they've been through the first step.

But for Google authentication (and Twitter, and Facebook), you only have a signIn method, no sign of a registeration step where you can filter which person can access your app.

So, am I missing something, or is it the only way firebase authentication works ?

Thanks a lot

Matthieu

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add allowed users to log into your app is from the Firebase back-end (c.f. the screenshot below):

[image]

Thus, you'll be able to choose which user will be granted to access your app.

Yes, it's a bit tedious, but as far as I know there's no other secured way to do this (or I didn't find it). You even can try to filter by email or anything else, but it's JS, so it can be changed client-side.

Otherwise, any person will be able to sign in your app.